# graphing velocity and time (v-t graph)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

The question goes like this:
If we push a body shortly uphill and it gets a starting velocity of $v \ ms^{-1}$,the coefficient of friction between the body and the surface is constant, represented by $k$, . Which graph shows the movement of the body correctly?

The answer on the back of the book is a graph that looks like A but I think it should be like B. Because the acceleration is the same (so if $y$ is the line, $y=kx+l$, $k$ should stay the same) and nothing else is mentioned. Am I right?

A:

[image: Graph A]

B :

[image: Graph B]

Comment: You need to clarify the question. What does "we push the body shortly up the hill and it gets starting velocity v" mean? You only push it for a short interval of time?

Comment: Yes we push it for the short interval just so it gets starting velocity and then it starts slowing down. Stops eventually and falls downhill.

Comment: Try to answer: what are the different forces on the body on the way up vs. the way down?

Comment: There are none. I cant see what your point is. (Friction works all the way and so does gravitational force.)

Comment: Ok i can see now.. basically friction is added in the up phase and substracted in down phase so acceleration is bigger in the up phase (with - infront). Ok i havent thought about it rationally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friction force changes direction during the motion.

- When the body is going uphill the parallel component of gravity with respect to the plane is pulling in one direction (downhill) and friction does the same.
- Viceversa, when the body is going downhill, gravity still pulls in that direction (downhill), while this time friction points uphill.

That's why you have different acceleration.

Anyway, when resolving basic mechanics problem, my advice is to think practically: for example, when riding a bike on a hill, can you slow down faster when you are going uphill or downhill?

Comment: Yes thats exactly my advice to myself. Ty anyways.